# android how to change <item> width and height

Tags: android, xml

I'm making a `<layer-list>` for drawable.

I have my background image, and I want the second layer to be smaller,
but it seems that doesn't matter what I'm writing inside my `android:layer_width` and `android:layer_height`.

The second layer size is still the same.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/picuser" 
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: if lint says that you must add width and height, then move your xml file to drawable instead of layout!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I hope this put you on the right direction:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/picuser"/>

    <item>

        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

As you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList), `<item>` doesn't have `layout_width`/`layout_height` attributes.

Comment: yeah i've seen it, but isn't there a way to define size of each layer? its really important..

Comment: Since API 23, there are attributes width,height,gravity on item

Comment: See also @oznus answer! Using padding works and it's easier.

Comment: if lint says that you must add width and height, then move your xml file to drawable instead of layout!

Comment: dear, bitmap does not support drawable resource, this answer doesn't help

Answer (score 38):

This is kind of a workaround, but it worked for me.
You can use padding in order to make the second drawable smaller.

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/circyle" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/plus" 
    android:top="10dp"
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:left="10dp" />
```

Comment: I upvoted, but now noticed that it seems to have no effect in my menu

Answer (score 26):

##### [TL;DR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68564673/8154765): Refer to [my newer, more concise answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68564673/8154765).

---

Actually, unlike it's been said, there are width and height attributes for `<item>` as well. Thanks to @Entreco for posting a demonstration of that.
`android:width` and `android:height` for `Drawable`s are similar to `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` for `View`s, unlike they can be set to neither `match_parent` nor `wrap_content`, but you can achieve the same behavior of `match_parent` by setting the attribute `android:gravity` to either `left|right` or `start|end` (to match the parent's width), or `top|bottom` (to match the parent's height).

Unfortunately, those attributes are only available starting from API level 23.

However, considering the above method I suggested in place of `match_parent` and that `android:width` and `android:height` attributes are available for `<size>` element (which has to be put inside a `<shape>`) without the need of a newer API level, you could use a simple workaround:

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <size
                android:width="152dp"
                android:height="152dp"/>

            <solid
                android:color="#00FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="left|right|top|bottom"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The above solution takes advantage of having a sized `<item>` (with a transparent `<shape>`) and an unsized one (with a `<bitmap>`) that has `android:gravity` set to `left|top|right|bottom` for matching both parent's dimensions. So, the real size of the `<bitmap>` will be determined by that of the unique sized `<item>` in the same parent.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Emil S for noticing that the above solution won't work when used as a window background. I can guess that at the time when the system creates a window with the background specified by the `android:windowBackground` attribute, no layout is performed as no process is started yet. So, Android will end up rasterizing the drawable at the screen size and stretch it to fill the whole window, I think. This would explain how that could happen. Indeed, a possible solution that I thought of, but I haven't tested yet, which unfortunately would be supported only starting from API level 24, is to use a custom drawable as a window background. It is possible by referencing an XML resource that uses a custom drawable, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44996958). This way, the issue should be solved since Android is forced to start the app process before showing the window, and so the drawable should be correctly laid out since it's aware of the window dimensions. This would lead, however, to an almost unnoticeable yet existing delay at the startup.

**EDIT:**

@João Carlos pointed out that my solution won't work (as it would cause a cyclic inheritance) when using an adaptive icon (those icons made by a background and a foreground, which support vector drawables). However, his point makes no sense, because adaptive icons require *API 26*: `android:width` and `android:height` attributes may be used on the splash screen or something, as they require *API 23*.
So, in order to get anything to work in any version of Android, you'll need to differentiate two drawables, the former for *API < 23*, using the solution I posted, and the latter for *API >= 23*, using the two attributes as I said at the beginning of this post.

Comment: if using the newer android icon for `ic_launcher`, which id defined by `backgroung.xml` and `foreground.xml`, the file that is used is the one inside `anydpi-v26` folder, instead of the `.png` ones; thus causing cycling xml recursion and crashing the app;

Comment: This only works if you use the layer-list in something that supports `wrap_content`. If you try to apply this to a splash screen it won't work. Took me some time to figure this out so I'm leaving this comment here so others don't have to spend time bug searching.

Answer (score 13):

From API Level 23 and higher, you can actually set the width & height of an item

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/splash_logo"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="100dp"/>
```

**NOTE:** Use `android:width` and `android:height` instead of `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- The android:opacity=”opaque” line is critical in preventing a flash 
of black as your theme transitions. -->
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">

    <!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <item
        android:height="100dp"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_bc_512"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Hands down the best answer this question has received

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a lot, but I couldn't find a reliable way to center the logo within an XML layout.
Finally, I found the following workaround:

```
mToolbar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.logo);
            if (mToolbar == null)
                return;
            int toolbarWidth = mToolbar.getWidth();
            int imageWidth = imageView.getWidth();
            imageView.setX((toolbarWidth - imageWidth) / 2);
        }
    });
```

layout_toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"                                                                   
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background"
    android:focusable="false"                                
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/toolbar_logo" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: The question is about a drawable. Using an `<ImageView>` to workaround the issue is out of topic.

Answer (score 1):

## Backward–compatible solution:

```
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <size
            android:width="152dp"
            android:height="152dp"/>

        <solid
            android:color="#00FFFFFF"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="left|right|top|bottom"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</item>
```

### Caveats and solutions:

1. ##### As a window background, that won't ever work

   - ###### API level ≥ 24

     For use in a window background, it may be worth experimenting with custom drawables. It is possible to reference them in the styles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44996958).
   - ###### API level < 24

     I haven't found any solution yet.
2. ##### Nor will that work for adaptive icons

   - ###### Refer to [Entreco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41480117/8154765)

     Since adaptive icons require API level 26, it is possible to use `android:width` and `android:height` attributes, which are available starting from API level 23.

---

###### For more information,

- refer to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46115699/8154765).

Answer (score 0):

For API level < 23, instead of using the defined height and width, you might want to use the following padding to make item smaller or bigger:

```
<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:top="8dp"
    android:left="8dp"
    android:right="8dp"
    android:bottom="8dp">
</item>
```