# creating background drawable using layer-list, icon getting stretched

Tags: android, layer-list

Hi I am trying to create a background `drawable` for my splash screen which I'll be setting in theme itself. But the bitmap drawable used to keep in the center is getting stretched and I am not able to figure how to keep it normal. Below is my drawable code:
**splash_screen_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="360"
            android:centerColor="@color/colorAccentXDark"
            android:endColor="@color/Black"
            android:gradientRadius="500dp"
            android:startColor="@color/colorAccentXDark"
            android:type="radial"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="50dp"
    android:top="50dp">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:innerRadius="500dp"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="1"
        android:shape="oval">
        <gradient
            android:angle="360"
            android:centerColor="@color/colorAccentXDark"
            android:endColor="@color/colorAccentXDark"
            android:gradientRadius="400dp"
            android:startColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:type="radial"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:gravity="center">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ty_logo" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Here is code where I am setting this drawable as background of an activity:

```
 <style name="TYTheme" parent="SearchActivityTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorAccentXDark</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_bg</item>
</style>
```

So here the bitmap drawable `ty_logo` is an `png` is  getting stretched in my phone. Since there is no `scaleType` option with `bitmapDrawable` I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: Did you find any answer to this question? I have the same problem right now and can't find a solution.

Comment: did not get the solution yet.

Answer (score 8):

Add `gravity` to your bitmap set to `center`.

```
<item android:gravity="center">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ty_logo" 
            android:gravity="center" />
</item>
```

Answer (score 4):

I *hope* that **ty_logo** is of suitable pixels and you have provided different pixels image for various device screens (`ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc`).
If not, do go through this answer to a similar problem you find yourself in :  [Resize images in bitmap in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42177842/7550472)

Otherwise, this can be easily solved if your *target version* is for **API 23** as `<item>` has ***width***,**height**,gravity attributes provided for them.

And if not, the following code should work, using **gravity** attribute for bitmap. Again, this is going by the assumption that your logo is not having more pixels than resolution of the devices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...

<item>
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ty_logo"
        android:gravity="center" />
</item>

...
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap bitmap inside [ScaleDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ScaleDrawable.html) `<scale>` and use `ScaleDrawable` inside `LayerListDrawable`.

```
<item android:gravity="center">
    <scale android:drawable="@drawable/ty_logo"
         android:scaleHeight="80%"
         android:scaleWidth="80%" >
    </scale> 
</item>
```

Comment: I tried adding this one but now ty_logo is not even visible.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple trick without using `Bitmap` or `width-height` or `margin`

##### Works for APIs+23

Drawables become stretched if we set its gravity other than center (APIs +23). Here is my solution i.e. **layer-list in layer-list**:

```
<layer-list>
<!-- Your original vector using layer-list in layer-list -->
<item
    android:gravity="top">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:gravity="center"
              android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_white_48dp"/>
    </layer-list>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

This works in APIs +23 because center-gravity has no stretch effect and keeps aspect ratio of drawable. But [in APIs 21 and 22 center-gravity is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34831142/6576302) so this approach will not work.