# Image distorted while using it as splash background

Tags: android, imageview

I am using an image of dimensions 1920 * 1080 as splash backgroud.
But this image scales on some devices.
I am using layer list as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/white" />
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_final" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

This is working for high res screen but the image is zoomed in low res device.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42177842/9017620