# Circle using layer-list drawable not visible properly in Kitkat

Tags: android, xml, drawable, android-drawable, layer-list

I am using the `layer-list` to draw the circle like[image]

I checked in Android N its working fine but in KitKat, only inner circle with the pink order is showing.

This is my layer-list drawable:

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- larger circle at the back -->
    <item
        android:width="60dp"
        android:height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <!-- inner circle -->
    <item
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/vivid_cerise" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: This happens with drawables. What you can do is use bitmap and canvas to create your circle programmatically and then set it your image or image background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pay attention to lint warnings:

[image]

`android:width` and `android:height` attributes are accessible from API 23 onwards, whereas KitKat is API 19.

Comment: Ya, that is the problem.how to give width and height in less then 23

Comment: That's not possible (yet) using `layer-list` drawable. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10706853/1083957) question.

Comment: put the width and height in a size tag inside the shape.