# How to set gravity for item for API level < 23

Tags: android, android-api-levels

How can I set gravity for `item` inside `layer-list` for API level < 23?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#A7A7A7"
                android:endColor="#C2C2C2"
                android:angle="315" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="14dp"
                android:topRightRadius="14dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:gravity="bottom"><!--This is not working-->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF5F5D" />
            <size android:height="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Don't waste your time - Check it:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46115699/7832102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF5F5D" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="14dp"
                android:topRightRadius="14dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="16dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:visible="true"
            android:dither="true"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#A7A7A7"
                android:endColor="#C2C2C2"
                android:angle="315" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="14dp"
                android:topRightRadius="14dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Nice trick:) Actually, it wouldn't be a general answer, but worked for my case. Thank you